# Filter through an array of Objects in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, oop, object

I have an array of objects when is being pulled in from a database and would like to return each object where the 'status' field is equal to 'No Answer':

```
array (size=21)
0 => 
  object(Customer)[4]
  public 'id' => string '12345' (length=6)
  public 'date' => string '2014-02-16' (length=10)
  public 'first_name' => string 'Jane' (length=5)
  public 'last_name' => string 'Doe' (length=4)
  public 'email' => string 'test@test.com' (length=21)
  public 'phone' => string '01782111444' (length=11)
  public 'status' => string 'No Answer' (length=14)
1 => 
object(Customer)[5]
  public 'id' => string '12346' (length=6)
  public 'date' => string '2014-02-19' (length=10)
  public 'first_name' => string 'John' (length=4)
  public 'last_name' => string 'Smith' (length=9)
  public 'email' => string 'no@no.com' (length=24)
  public 'phone' => string '01606555666' (length=11)
  public 'status' => string 'Left Message' (length=12)
```

It seems like I would need to use array_filter() but cant seem to get it to work

Comment: `array_filter()` seems right to me.  Can you show us the invocation you've been trying?

Comment: Is this not a criterion you could add to a database query? How is it stored/accessed?

Comment: I want to display different status' separated by tabs so rather than keep going back to the database with 5/6 variations of the same query I thought it would be better to select all then filter the array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like @Wiseguy commented, you *should* be doing this in your query, not the code.

See [`array_filter()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php):

```
array_filter($array, function($i) {
  if(strtolower($i->status) == 'no answer') { return true; }
  else { return false; }
});
```

Comment: Works perfect, thanks. Is it not better to filter an array of results then, than make multiple calls to the database?

Comment: @user1105056 Your question implies that you're throwing away the results that are filtered out. If you're making use of them elsewhere, then feel free to ignore the suggestions.